# can not use some of my aliases with bare repo

Tags: git, git-alias

I have some aliases like:

```
add-and-commit = !git add -A && git commit -m
last = !git --no-pager log -1 --oneline
stash-and-reset = !git stash && git reset --hard HEAD
```

I track my dotfiles with a bare repo.

```
d = !git --git-dir=/media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_DailyBackups/dotfilesBackup --work-tree=$HOME
```

Now the problem is that, i can use:

```
git add-and-commit
git last
git stash-and-reset
```

But I can not do:

```
git d add-and-commit
git d last
git d stash-and-reset
```

Is there any solution for that?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with 'But I can not do <commands>', what is the resulting error message?

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

```
git init --bare $HOME/.dotfiles
touch $HOME/.dotfiles/.test

git config --global alias.ac '!git add -A && git commit -m'
git config --global alias.dot '!git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles/ $HOME/.dotfiles'
git dot ac "Commit message"
```

The `dot` command also works in combination with `last` and `stash-and-reset`.

```
git dot last
4c1db03 (HEAD -> master) testtest
```

*P.S.* I didn't set `--work-tree=$HOME` because I would get too many files, but it would work.

Another way to solve your problem is to create a `bash alias` to track your dotfiles, this can also be used in combination with other git commands and aliases. See for instance [this article](https://medium.com/toutsbrasil/how-to-manage-your-dotfiles-with-git-f7aeed8adf8b)!

Comment: Uhu! It is a bare repo. My bare repo is located in `/media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_DailyBackups/dotfilesBackup`. And it tracks my `$HOME` directory.

Comment: You can find more details about the question in https://www.reddit.com/r/git/comments/jdl11c/can_not_use_some_of_my_aliases_with_bare_repo/

Comment: So what happens when yiu replace it by `media/blueray/WDPurple/_DataBackup/_Work/_DailyBackups/dotfilesBackup/.git`?

Comment: @blueray I have updated the answer. Please let me know if this works for you and answer the question as resolved if this helped you :)

Comment: Check `dotfiles config --local status.showUntrackedFiles no` on the article you have referred. It solves the problem of "I didn't set --work-tree=$HOME because I would get too many files, but it would work." It actually does not work.

Comment: Ah thanks, i thought i misconfigured something :) what i meant was that the combination of aliases didn't throw an error