# function to modify bash command based on condition

Tags: bash, zsh

The current state of the function is like:

```
function git() {
    if  [[ $@ =~ ^"d untrack-all" ]]
    then
        echo "g d rm --cached -r ~"
    elif [[ $@ =~ ^"d add-and-commit" ]]
    then
        echo "g d add ~ && g d commit -am \"$_\""
    elif [[ $@ =~ ^"d sb" ]]
    then
        echo "git d branch | rofi -dmenu | xargs git checkout"
    elif [[ $@ =~ ^"d stash-and-reset" ]]
    then
        echo "git d stash && git d reset --hard HEAD"
    elif [[ $@ =~ ^"d last" ]]
    then
        echo "git d --no-pager log -1 --oneline"
    else
        echo $0" "$@
    fi
}
```

What I am expecting is,

if I run the command `git d untrack-all` it will actually run `g d rm --cached -r ~`
if I run the command `git d add-and-commit` it will actually run `g d add ~ && g d commit -am \"$_\"`
...
If the pattern does not match, it will run the command as it is. For example, if I run `git status`, it will run `git status`.

In the given codem If I replace `echo` with `eval`, it closes the terminal. What should I do?

Comment: Please [edit] to clarify. This can't be about [tag:bash] and about [tag:zsh] at the same time. Which one is it?

Comment: You don't need to use echo so echo "g d rm --cached -r ~" should be g d rm --cached -r ~etc

Comment: @RamanSailopal what about the last line? `$0" "$@`. How can I say, run as it is.

Comment: @RamanSailopal Please add it as an answer though. I think it qualifies for an accepted answer.

Comment: I find this approach a little bit complex. I would try to play with git and bash aliases first.

Comment: @mouviciel I tried it already https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416625/can-not-use-some-of-my-aliases-with-bare-repo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to use echo so:

```
echo "g d rm --cached -r ~"
```

should be:

```
g d rm --cached -r ~
```

etc. In the last case, you can run

```
bash -c $0" "$@
```

Comment: I have changed my function name from `git` to `g`. Now `zsh -c "git $@"` works.